# how to simplify below programming code in verilog or systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have below codes needed to simplify. but it has a bit difficult for me to do. Would anyone can provide some help here ?

**The number of u0, u1,... is determined by a feature**.
The same as the number of a0, a1...

If the feature is 2 or 4, it's easy to handle as what it like now. But if feature is a very big number, we have to code much more lines here. So I'd like to change these code into deperl to simplify.

```
assign result_u0_a0 = start_u0_a0 
                    & (start_u0_a1) | (id_u0_a1 == id_u0_a0)
                    & (start_u1_a0) | (id_u1_a0 == id_u0_a0)
                    & (start_u1_a1) | (id_u1_a1 == id_u0_a0);
assign result_u0_a1 = start_u0_a1
                    & (start_u0_a0) | (id_u0_a0 == id_u0_a1)
                    & (start_u1_a0) | (id_u1_a0 == id_u0_a1)
                    & (start_u1_a1) | (id_u1_a1 == id_u0_a1);
assign result_u1_a0 = start_u1_a0 
                    & (start_u0_a0) | (id_u0_a0 == id_u1_a0)
                    & (start_u0_a1) | (id_u0_a1 == id_u1_a0)
                    & (start_u1_a1) | (id_u1_a1 == id_u1_a0);
assign result_u1_a1 = start_u1_a1
                    & (start_u0_a0) | (id_u0_a0 == id_u1_a1)
                    & (start_u0_a1) | (id_u0_a1 == id_u1_a1)
                    & (start_u1_a0) | (id_u1_a0 == id_u1_a1);
```

Comment: does it even compile? i do not understand how this code should work. At least you need to provide declarations of all variables. You should remove all assignments `=` from the expressions, it makes the code non-readable at minimum.

Comment: I agree this question needs some work. 

Comment: I have not problem with the format. It maybe strange for a C/C++ programmer but in Verilog these kinds of code structures are seen quite often. I **do** wonder if the code is copied OK.  &  (start_u0_a1  | (id_u0_a1==id_u0_a0) ) ???

Comment: well, in this case it is a single`=` which makes it an assignment, actually a multiple assignments to the same variables in rhs of the contiguous assignment operations. From the top of my head i do not even know if it is legal in verilog. I know that this works for registers in always blocks though.

Comment: What do you mean by "change these code into _deperl_"

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am sorry it's my mistake. The '=' should be replaced with '=='.

Comment: deperl is a language to simply the code. for example if we have below code in a.sv

    assign u0 = v0_balabala;
    assign u1 = v1_balabala;
    ...
    assign u31 = v31_balabala;

then we can change it into a.sv.dpl file as shown below.

    ; for (my $idx = 0; $idx < 32; $idx++) {
        assign u$idx$ = v$idx$_balabala;
    ; }


That's a way to save the effort on code line. ^_^

Comment: @RockyZheng i fixed your example based on your comment. Still to try to answer your question one needs more info, at least about declaration widths of all signals. The `==` operation produces a one-bit result (zero-extendible to the width of the context). Also your code has a potential for infinite 0-delay loop. you need to provide logic behind other variables as well.

Comment: and i guess another question. Since you messed up '=', did you also mess up `|` and `&`. Did you mean bitwise operators or logical operators like `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply write a perl or python code that generates the required output.
In Verilog or Systemverilog you can write a macro. However they do not support [MACROS with Variable number of arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro). Which means you can not write a macro that works both for 2 and 4.